# Fatal error : Class 'Dotnev' not found in compiled in Laravel 5.0.0

Tags: laravel

Good night !

I am working with PHP now and I try to update the project but I have this problem  when I use composer update.

My composer file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"

    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

This project has been developing since last year , for this reason I think I have problem with this , could anyone helps to me ?

Comment: I don't think this is related to your composer packages rather it should be your model or controller.

Comment: But , if yesterday works correctly , it is possible that the composer fails ? I need a simple composer to check this possibility.

Comment: try `composer install` and then `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I would suggest doing a `php artisan clear-compiled` as well. If it doesn't work probably this thread can help you out: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/upgrading-to-l5-and-getting-class-not-found-on-composer-update